# DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147024809 CordovaApp Windows10

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Whenever I am trying to deploy my cordova UWP app to windows 10 device. I got this kind of issue. I had changed 'PhoneProductID' also. Still issue persist. 
Below is the error.

> DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147024809   CordovaApp Windows10

May I know what is the root cause for this issue?

Comment: May I know why down vote for it? Can you please explain? If you won't understand the question or you need some more information then pleases try to ask rather than down vote..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please ensure you have already [Enabled your device for development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development).

Secondly, please try to uninstall the app from device, restart the Visual Studio and rebuild solution and then try again.

If you are trying to deploy UWP App to Windows 10 mobile 14356 with Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, in that case, this is a known issue. Please try to upgrade your windows 10 to resolve the issue. Details please check this [similar thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9304af75-a544-4c08-9334-f807610878d1/cannot-deploy-uwp-app-to-win10m-14356-dep0001-unexpected-error-2147014836?forum=wpdevelop).

If until now you still cannot resolve your issue, please try to narrow your issues by following steps:

- Create a blank UWP app and deploy it to the current device to see if it works.
- Deploy your cordova UWP app to another windows 10 device to see if it works.

And then provide the testing environment details and reproduce steps for further looking.

Comment: Thanks @Sunteen .. Device is already enabled for development. Uninstalled the old app and tried to install it again but facing issue.. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Professional Update 3. I had created black UWP app and able to deployed successfully on device. But again I did the modifications with latest UWP app and tried to make replica of previous app. But got same issue again.

Comment: @androidOnHigh  "But again I did the modifications with latest UWP app and tried to make replica of previous app. But got same issue again" What does this mean?  Could you please check the description carefully? What's your testing environment? What's the windows 10 device version? What's your UWP app target version? Did you have another device for testing?

Comment: I mean to say that I tried with old project but that wasn't working. Hence I tried to install plugins and other code in newly created project. But got same issue again. No currently I have only one device. Its microsoft windows 10 device. Min and max target version is 10.0.10240.0.